# Only serialize on GET not POST Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I only want the `AnchorSerializer()` to serialize on a GET request so it return the serialized object as a response. On a POST request when creating an `AnchorToUser` object an integer is expected.

```
class AnchorToUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Add the username from the user object relation.
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    # Serialize the nested anchor.
    anchor = AnchorSerializer() # Should only be used with GET.
    class Meta:
        model = AnchorToUser
        fields = (
            'anchor',
            'user',
            'created_at'
        )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use different serializers for `GET` and `POST`.

```
class AnchorToUserGetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    anchor = AnchorSerializer(read_only=True) # only used for serialization

    class Meta:
        model = AnchorToUser
        fields = ('anchor', 'user', 'created_at')


class AnchorToUserPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    anchor = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True) # accept integer values

    class Meta:
        model = AnchorToUser
        fields = ('anchor', 'user', 'created_at')
```

To decide what serializer to use, you can then override the `get_serializer_class()` method.

In your views or viewsets, you can do something like:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return AnchorToUserPostSerializer
    return AnchorToUserGetSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this has changed since 2016, but I had to have my viewset as such for this to work;

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.action == 'create':
        return AnchorToUserPostSerializer
    return AnchorToUserGetSerializer
```